# Why does Brotli Command Line only allow up to level 9?

Tags: nginx, brotli, ngx-brotli

According to the main [GitHub page](https://github.com/google/ngx_brotli#brotli_comp_level) for Brotli there are 11 levels of dynamic compression.

> Sets on-the-fly compression Brotli quality (compression) level. Acceptable values are in the range from 0 to 11.

However [another page](https://github.com/google/brotli/blob/master/c/tools/brotli.md) of the project shows that the command line only supports 9 levels of compression

> compression level (0-9); bigger values cause denser, but slower compression

I tested to see if level 9 from the command line was the same as level 11 dynamic compression. However it is not.

Is there any way compress a file using the command line with level 11 compression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/google/brotli/issues/725) explains it best:

> The default quality is mentioned:
>
> ```
>   -Z, --best      use best compression level (11) (default)
> ```
>
> I think the single dash (-0 to -9) quality parameters are just for convenience, the problem is that by [convention](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html) a single dash parameter can only by followed by a single character, so -10 or -11 would break the convention.

Comment: Thus, compression level `10` is impossible from the command line?

Comment: Not at all! From the first line (https://github.com/google/brotli/issues/725) you can see it's possible with the `-q 10` or `--quality=10` switches. There just isn't a single digit/character switch. Guess it would be easy enough to add one if there was demand for it, but would imagine most go to 11 (`-Z`) when at that level.